# Building Mutation Graphql Query

Tags: graphql

I am quite new to GraphQL so I am struggling a little bit to understand how to write a proper Query on the front-end.

So, this is the Mutation I've on the server-side

```
type Mutation {
    addTerminal(terminal: TerminalInput): Terminal
    // other stuff not related
}
type Terminal {
    terminalId: String!
    merchantId: String
    terminalDesignator: String
}

input TerminalInput {
    terminalId: String!
    merchantId: String
    terminalDesignator: String
}
```

I believe it is using the right structure, but when I try to connect with the client-side im a bit confused.

This is the query I've on the front-end.

```
export const ADD_TERMINAL_MUTATION = () => (
```

`mutation addTerminalMutation($terminalId: TerminalInput) {
      addTerminal(terminal: { terminalId: $terminalId }) {
        terminalId,
        merchantId,
        terminalDesignator,
      }
    }`

);

and when I fire it to the server, I receive the following feedback:

> Variable "$terminalId" of type "TerminalInput" used in position expecting type "String!".

So I changed to this:

```
addTerminal(terminal: { terminalId: "123" }) {
```

and got the error

> Variable "$terminalId" is never used in operation "addTerminalMutation".

If I change to

```
mutation addTerminalMutation($terminalId: String!) {
```

It says that the TerminalId wasnt provided, but if I log it, it can be seen

[image]

So, what is the right way to write this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `addTerminalMutation($terminalId: TerminalInput)` to `addTerminalMutation($terminalId: String!)` to indicate the correct type.

Comment: If I do this, it says the terminalID wasnt provided. Variable "$terminalId" of required type "String!" was not provided.

Answer (score 0):

First, the

```
Variable "$terminalId" is never used in operation "addTerminalMutation".
```

is caused by passing the variable in line

```
mutation addTerminalMutation($terminalId: TerminalInput)
```

and never referencing it later.

The problem in the second part seems that the terminalId parameter is not decomposed.
The parameter in the line

```
addTerminal(terminal: { terminalId: $terminalId })
```

is expected to be a String!.

You could do something like this:

```
addTerminal(input: $terminalId)
```

to pass in the whole terminal id object.

See this for further info:
https://blog.apollographql.com/designing-graphql-mutations-e09de826ed97